# Magento 1.9.0.1 Grouped Product Drop Down problem with sub-products quantity

Tags: product, ce-1.9.0.1, grouped-products, customer-account, quantity

I replaced the table view with a drop down view. Now, the file "template/catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml" looks like this:

..

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" class="add-to-cart" id="product_addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId()?>"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
<div style="float:right;border:1px solid;padding:5px; width: 100%;">
    <?php if($_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <?php $_subAssociatedProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($_product); ?>
        <?php if(count($_subAssociatedProducts)){?>
            <!--<div class="groupedTitle">Dimensiune / Grosime</div>-->
            <select id="grouped_products" name="grouped_products" onchange="addSuperQty('<?php echo $_product->getId()?>',this.value);">
                <?php foreach ($_subAssociatedProducts as $_item) {?>
                <option value="<?php echo $_item->getId()?>" id="<?php echo number_format($_item->getFinalPrice(),2); ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName())?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        <?php }?>
        <span id="span_<?php echo $this->getId()?>"></span>
        <input type="button" value="-" id="minus1" class="minus" />
        <input type="text" size="3" name="qty" onchange="changeQty(this.value,'<?php echo $_product->getId()?>');" id="<?php echo $_product->getId()?>_qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $_product->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <input type="button" value="+" id="add1" class="plus" />
    <?php else:?>
        <input type="button" value="-" id="minus1" class="minus" />
        <input type="text" size="3" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $_product->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <input type="button" value="+" id="add1" class="plus" />

    <?php endif; ?>
    <button type="button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
</div>
</form>
```

..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addSuperQty(spanId,itemId)
    {
        var qty = document.getElementById(spanId+'_qty').value;
        var ID = 'span_'+spanId;
        document.getElementById(ID).innerHTML = '<input type="hidden" value="'+qty+'" id="super_group_'+spanId+'"  name="super_group['+itemId+']" />';
    }

    function changeQty(val,itemId)
    {
        document.getElementById('super_group_'+itemId).value = val;
    }
</script>
```

For all my grouped products, the default value is 0. So this:

```
<?php echo $_product->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>
```

Displays 0 for the quantity each time. What is wrong? On older Magento versions it worked.

When I set a bigger product quantity and try to add the product (sub product) into my account, I receive this error: **Please specify the quantity of product(s)**.

Please help me to fix the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to apply the same as Pascut, the first block of code I assume it fully replaces the file "template/catalog/product/view/type/grouped.phtml". The second javascript block, where should I put it? I tried but doesnt work. Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/150822)

Answer (score 3):

The name of the input box is wrong in your case. It must be super_group[#item_id]. Please replace item_id with the actual #item id. You can achieve it using jquery/javascript, etc.

Comment: I'm using javascript. Please take a look again at the code from above. I added the js part. Still not working.

Comment: It was a javascript error. Thanks for telling me about js :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem.
I used $this instead of $_product on this line:

```
<span id="span_<?php echo $this->getId()?>"></span>
```

So now I have:

```
<span id="span_<?php echo $_product->getId()?>"></span>
```

There was a JavaScript error. I was too sleepy to notice this error. (use Firebug)